# Transferring Perl Modules from a folder, to the pre-installed perl on Mac

Tags: macos, perl

Salutations

I am having an issue right now. Recently I have download Bioperl, but I made a mistake somewhere in the installation process. I dont know the correct terminology, but what I do know is that the perl modules I downloaded are suppose to be with the default perl (aka #!/usr/bin/perl) along with the use strict, and use warnings.
But they are located in this directory.

/Users/JamesPK/TerminalWork/lib/perl5/5.16.2/Bio/AlignIO/fasta.pm

So right now, I need to transfer all those modules from bioperl in the home directoy, to where ever the  #!/usr/bin/perl is located.

Anybody have any ideas or insights to tackling this problem ? 
Plus is there an effective unix command I can use for transfering these files?  I am still getting use to programming on a Mac.

Cheers

Comment: Best just to reinstall it properly. Make sure env var `PERL_MM_OPT`, `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL5LIB` aren't set in the shell you'll use to install the module. Make sure `cpan` configuration vars `makepl_arg` and `mbuildpl_arg` are empty. (`echo 'o conf makepl_arg' | cpan` and `echo 'o conf mbuildpl_arg' | cpan` will show `[]` for them.)